# Is the file extension important when a MIME type is involved? Does this affect other things on a server?

Tags: html, css, mime

Is the file extension important?

For instance, I have a CSS style sheet. I call it "hi.js", and then link to it with its MIME type as text/CSS. Does this work? Is it "illegal" to do?

Edit: it was just a question jeez, not like I'm actually going to do this

Comment: What is a name? A worthless pile of characters.

Comment: Why do you want to do this? is not useful at all! And of course is a bad practice to make a good and clean code...

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol Well, its the main way for text editors to found out which syntax highlighting to use. So you can't really say it's a 'worthless' pile of characters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When HTTP is involved, file extensions are more or less meaningless. It is the content type that matters (the one that is sent by the server, not the one you tell the browser to expect using the `type` attribute).

However, using misleading file extensions will:

- Make it harder to configure your server (since you'll have to tell it to send a different content-type for that file)
- Make anyone who has to maintain your code (including you from 6 months in the future) very unhappy with you

Answer (score 1):

No, the file extension is not important.

HTTP has no concept of "files", only requests/responses with content/headers. If the response header identifies the type of the response content, the URL by which it is requested (which is where the "file extension" is) makes no difference.

The URL could be:

- /style.css
- /style.js
- /foo.bar
- /CssGenerator.php?styleIdentifier=MyStyle
- /some/style
- etc.

It makes no difference to the content and headers of the response.